# IE10 (9,8) does not recognize DOCTYPE xhtml

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, mootools, doctype

IE10 rejects to launch some jQuery code, as far I found on runtime somewhere a doctype is wrong detected and prepended with 4.01 transitional version.

In IE's developer tools viewing the console I see
`HTML1524: Invalid DOCTYPE. The shortest valid doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>"` and following (runtime modified) html:

I believe both misuse of DOCTYPE and some jQuery not working have a common reason, but did not find what it is.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><HTML 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" slick-uniqueid="1"><HEAD><META 
content="IE=10.000" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">

<META http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250">
<TITLE>....
```

While **IE states to run in standards mode, still some things do not work** (mainly replacing the links with jQuery's on click events to show content instead loading whole new page - used for unpacking other menu branch using accordion, original links in category headers with href are fallback only for case jQuery fails to animate accordion)

Too many other on click events or jQuery UI functions to make link to look like button fail to function in IE while working in other browsers.

Original HTML as provided from server is following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="sk" lang="sk">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1250" />
<title>...
```

I am forced to use both MooTools and jQuery and know the slick-uniqueid in htm attributes is from Moo, I don't know if it may be the same who edits the doctype, but I'm sure it happens in IE browsers only, Chrome and Firefox just work OK.

jQuery scripts are loaded from external js file, wrapped in **jQuery(function() {..** and all use full variable name jQuery instead of dollarsign, for example  `jQuery("#myid").click( function(e){..`.

As using both mootools and jQuery (I know I should not but need some mootools plugin for slideshow with thumbnails and KenBurns effect) and **jQuery is loaded first** and within scripts I use only **jQuery()... so the $ dollarsign is all free for MooTools** to use later on as it is loaded just if needed, within the body (not sure that's OK but that's the way how 'visualslideshow' presented it).

I'd be glad to hear any ideas or suggestions on how to identify or fix it to get the jQuery working right (v1.8).

Comment: You should definitely only have one DOCTYPE, so that's one problem you need to solve. You should look at [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) for freeing the `$` from jQuery's clutches.

Comment: i see you did not read what this is about, something prepends the html 4.01 itself, I do not have it there on purpose, im looking to find why it is being added there if using IE and how to get rid of it...

Comment: i send from server ONLY XHTML doctype, the other one 4.01 html get prepended on runtime if browsed by IE and I don know why

Comment: too in console i do not see any jQ related error, it just silently stops working... only error I see in console is this HTML1524 (invalid dostype) and warning from fb that FB.getLoginStatus was called before calling FB.init, and one css warning (:visited vs :link color)... nothing else is there

Comment: `i see you did not read what this is about` - what a delightful way of helping me understand your complicated question. Good luck getting an answer on this one.

Comment: sorry if offended you, but yeah because i wrote i know I should have only one DOCTYPE, and I HAVE ONLY ONE in the produced code from server, but under IE, on runtime it adds it self the other one...  and I just seek to find a way to detect why it happens, where it happens and how to fix it

Comment: too as mentioned in the post, all affected jQuery code does not depend on the compatibility mode as I do not use the dollar sign, but the whole jQuery identifier/function

Comment: Let's try again... I don't think the doctype and JavaScript issues are related. Can you try adding the [recommended `doctype`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh779632.aspx) for IE10? Does the double doctype get added still? As for jQuery, even if you don't use the `$`, jQuery still defines it. You **must** call `jQuery.noConflict()` to release the `$`

Comment: Another symptom of this bug it that if you save a perfectly valid XHTML 1.0 Strict page to your hard disk, (which IE apparently renders correctly in Standards mode), IE10 still erroneously adds the extra above-mentioned bogus HTML 4 Transitional DOCTYPE and "fixes" all the webpage markup for you! (Clearly an IE BUG IMO.)

Comment: There is a button that says: "Click to accept this answer because it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution.". If you still need help, improve the questions if it is related or create another question.

Answer (score 15):

Change your DOCTYPE to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

(using XHTML strict instead of transitional)

IE10 will stop throwing the error in the console. I'm not sure why IE10 doesn't like transitional XHTML any more. If anyone has a way for IE10 to recognize the XHTML 1.0 Transitional DOCTYPE, that would be awesome.

Comment: hmm strict is too strict as there are some elements/atributes not allowed on strict that I need to have, most importantly iframes used to include some remote code /facebook and others - fb has alternatives without iframes but there is still other why I need it/

Comment: This is the correct reason for the issue.  Microsoft is pushing developers away from "depending" on transitional doc types.

Comment: Yes, IE10 appears to operate in standards mode when a valid page is served with an XHTML Strict DOCTYPE, but (interestingly), if you save this page as an html file to your local computer, it adds the extra bogus HTML 4.0 doctype and "fixes" all the page's markup to be HTML 4 Transitional. IMHO - This is clearly an IE BUG.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get rid of the error by using

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

instead of

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue. It worth looking at any external libraries you are using. I was using BXSlider and it wasn't happy with jQuery 1.8 on IE10. Due to which IE10 was failing and showing message.

```
  HTML1524: Invalid DOCTYPE. The shortest valid doctype is "<!DOCTYPE html>
```

My solution was to upgrade my JQuery to 1.9.1 and also include jQuery migrate.

```
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me in IE and FireFox, because when i included the css i wrote `"< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/javascript ..."`

i just change it to `type="text/css"` and it works.

Comment: I wish it was that easy. Checked and this is not the case for me, i have all css and js includes named ok. But hey thanks to know that could cause it too

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your <s>second</s> first `DOCTYPE` definition, the W3C <s>is missing a</s> has an extra `c`:

```
                                                                             v-- extra "c"
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3c.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Try fixing that and test again.

Comment: Actually, the "c" shouldn't be there.

Comment: You are right, mistyped myself at the browser to confirm the address and assumed the `c` was needed

Comment: the first is the one "dont know where and why added" however yes the version with "c" should work but official list mentions the "not-with-c" version of their website, as shown here http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html